# How to detect External Display is connected to Windows Phone?

Tags: c#, windows-phone

In Android, if the device is connected to an External Display, it gives a broadcast.

I want to know how to do detect this in Windows Phone.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a good way to ask a question here. Did you try _anything_ so far to solve your problem? Show your effort first so people might show theirs. Please read [FAQ], [ask] and [help] as a start..

Answer (score 0):

Easy.

```
///<summary>True when an external display is connected to the MicroHDMI output of this Windows Phone</summary>
static bool isExternalDisplayConnected()
{
    return false;  // No windows phone device has MicroHDMI output, nor any other external display output.
}
```